# Accidentally changed the path of an RSS feed page in Views to refer to a menu link item and cannot access Views menu anymore

Tags: views, debugging

I cannot access views from the Structure Menu in Drupal 8 anymore. I accidentally changed the path of an RSS feed page in Views to refer to a menu link item and cannot access the Views menu anymore.

How does one fix this? I get an error that says "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later when trying to access View Menu."

The report log says the following:

"InvalidArgumentException: The internal path component 'http://localhost/drupal/News-Press' is external. You are not allowed to specify an external URL together with internal:/. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromInternalUri() (line 409 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Url.php)."

Comment: You may export the configuration (drush cex), search for taht view, change the path in the configuration files and then import the configuration (drush cim).

Comment: @sanzante how do I do that?

Comment: Do you have drush installed? And, do you have access to other admin URLs like /admin/config/development/configuration?

Comment: @sanzante No I do not have drush installed but I do have access to every other admin URL except for Views.

Comment: @sanzante I've replaced the line with the path and get the following error.... Could not extract the contents of the tar file. The error message is Invalid checksum for file "2-23-15-47/automated_cron.settings.ymlinterval: 10800 _core: default_config_hash: fUksROt4FfkAU9BV4hV2XvhTBSS2nTNrZS4U7S-tKrs PK/PK" : 48600 calculated, 0 expected

Comment: @sanzante do you know of any editors that can do this? I have windows 10

Comment: No, sorry, I don't use Windows so I don't know which is good, but should be opklenty of them. Ah, it's better if you comments in the answer, becuase this commetns are not related to the question but to my answer. This way if anyone stumble upon this question and answer gets info more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your configuration to files, then edit the file that holds wour faulty view, edit the URL, save it and import the configuiratin again.

To do this:

1. Go to `/admin/config/development/configuration/full/export` and click 'Export'. Your browser should donwload tar.gz file.
2. Uncompress the file to see all your site configuration splitted in multiple files.
3. The file that holds your faulty view file should be views.view.NAME_OF_THE_VIEW. Edit it and look for a line with the view path. It should be:

   > path: {wrong path}
4. Change to the right path and save the file.
5. Compress again all files to get again a tar.gz file. Is the same that you downloaded but with the file you have just updated.
6. Go to `/admin/config/development/configuration/full/import` and upload your tar.gz file with the new configuration.

Drupal should update the configuration and change that view url.

**Udpate**

Unfortunately it seems there's a bug with views that can arise when editing file in Windows (an probably Mac):
[Importing tar file causes Archive_Tar error](https://www.drupal.org/node/1914652)

> I had the same problem and I found that I could not open the tar
>   neither. So I tryed other exports. I found that when I don't export
>   views settings, the tar is good. It's only when I put some specific
>   views in the export that the tar does not work.

**Second update**
As @user3531869 says, it's possible to update one single file of configuration to avoid the mentioned bug. To do this go to `/admin/config/development/configuration/single/export` and select the element you want to export (in this case select View as configuration type, Aggregator RSS Feed as configuration name), copy the the code that Drupal returns, edit to fix the path and the go to `/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import`, select View as configuration type, paste the edited code in the text area and clicj `Import`.

Comment: @user3531869 Make sure you edit the file with an editor that doesn't change lines form Unix to other system (Mac/Windows). It's only options I can guess. If not, you may install drush and do same process with dirsh (export with drush, edit, import with drush), but this is beyond this single answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out how to get it working now. I went to Development>Configuration synchronization, clicked on Export tab, clicked on Single item sub-tab, Selected View as configuration type, Aggregator RSS Feed as configuration name, copied the code in the window underneath...clicked on the import tab above, clicked single item, selected view as configuration type, and pasted the code in the window below and modified the single line with the PATH and clicked import. Views now works

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention you could import a single file, sorry. I'm glad you fixed it.

Comment: Yeah no problem